# How to record Video with playing audio in background and It should not record any other sound using microphone?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, video-processing, audio-processing, nextlevel

I am trying to record video by playing the audio in background. but right now while recording video it record the other sounds also that are coming from any other source. I want to record only audio which I am playing in the Background.

I tried to record video first and then merged the audio in the same clip, but it taking time to processing. Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean record video by playing the audio in the background? Are you trying to add music etc to a video? That is best done in a video editing software as post-processing, not during recording time

Comment: @jonnor yes, I want to add music into video. suppose my video total length is 15sec with 3 separate video clips. Now I want to add music to it.